# ASP.net c# Parse int as datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, casting

Given a time:

> 1286294501433

Which represents milliseconds passed since 1970, how do we convert this to a DateTime data type?  EG:

```
transactionTime = "1286294501433";
UInt64 intTransTime = UInt64.Parse(transactionTime);
DateTime transactionActualDate = DateTime.Parse(intTransTime.ToString());
```

Throws:

> String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

Please note all times passed into this function are guaranteed to be *after* 1970.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(1286294501433);
```

You might also need to specify the `DateTimeKind` explicitly, depending on your exact requirements:

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
             .AddMilliseconds(1286294501433);
```

Answer (score 1):

And to simplify it even further and also take your local timezone into account:

Just create this integer number extension -

```
  public static class currency_helpers {
    public static DateTime UNIXTimeToDateTime(this int unix_time) {
      return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(unix_time).ToLocalTime();
    }
  }
```

And then call it wherever like this:

```
var unix_time = 1336489253;    
var date_time = unix_time.UNIXTimeToDateTime();
```

The value of `date_time` is:

```
5/8/2012 10:00:53 AM
```

(via: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10081/UNIX-timestamp-to-System-DateTime?msg=2494329#xx2494329xx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is unix time its the number of seconds, so

```
int unixtimestamp=int.Parse(str);
new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0).AddSeconds(unixtimestamp);
```

like this [fetcher guy said](http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/unix-time-in-c-123865.htm).

wiki says

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system
>   for describing points in time, defined
>   as the number of seconds elapsed since
>   midnight proleptic Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC) of January 1,
>   1970, not counting leap seconds. I