# Trivia: How to convert a JSON2.org DateTime string to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, json, datetime

Asp.Net MVC 2 Futures doesn't seem to handle JSON DateTime well (including double and decimal values).  As such, I setup all inputs as string, used Data Validation, and things worked pretty well.

However, I have this JSON2.js date from Firefox 3.6:

```
"/Date(1288296203190)/"
```

How do I turn this in to a valid date in C#?

```
var a = new DateTime(1288296203190);
```

That doesn't give the right date (1/2/0001 11:47:09 AM) instead of Thu Oct 28 2010 16:03:23 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time).  It's probably because a 32 bit integer is only 10 digits.  However, this fails too:

```
var a = Int64.Parse("1288296203190");
var b = new DateTime(a);
```

b's value is 1/2/0001 11:47:09 AM.

What did it do?  Wrap?  Is this some kind of time travel "signed bit" issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the difference in epoch.  Looks like the JSON2.js date you have uses the unix epoch (January 1, 1970) measured in ms.  From the System.DateTime(long ticks) documenttion:

> expects A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

Something like this should get you what you want.

```
var unixEpoch = DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var ticksSinceEpoch = 1288296203190 * 10000;
var time = new DateTime(unixEpoch.Ticks + ticksSinceEpoch);
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Add new in front of DateTime and subtract four hours for the time zone, and your answer is correct.  :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe something like this DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

Comment: Probably need Daylight savings in there somewhere too

Answer (score 1):

And there is even better way (which also takes your local timezone into account):

Just create this integer number extension -

```
  public static class currency_helpers {
    public static DateTime UNIXTimeToDateTime(this int unix_time) {
      return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(unix_time).ToLocalTime();
    }
  }
```

And then call it wherever like this:

```
var unix_time = 1336489253;    
var date_time = unix_time.UNIXTimeToDateTime();
```

The value of `date_time` is:

```
5/8/2012 10:00:53 AM
```

(via: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10081/UNIX-timestamp-to-System-DateTime?msg=2494329#xx2494329xx)

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonDate = "/Date(1288296203190+0530)/";
var strSec = jsonDate.Substring(6, 13);
var strTimeZone = jsonDate.Substring(19, 5);
sec = double.Parse(strSec);
var timeZoneHr = double.Parse(strTimeZone);
var timeZoneMin = timeZoneHr % 100;
 timeZoneHr = Math.Ceiling(timeZoneHr / 100);
var date = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
     .AddMilliseconds(sec)
     .AddHours(timeZoneHr)
     .AddMinutes(timeZoneMin);
```

I parsed the string myself. Its working fine for me. Anybody have other optimized way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically the same as this one: [ASP.net c# Parse int as datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871299/asp-net-c-parse-int-as-datetime).

And I think the accepted answer there is better than @matheeeny's answer (although matheeeny explained well the problem of OP's original solution).

I'll copy here [LukeH's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871299/asp-net-c-parse-int-as-datetime/3871316#3871316):

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(1286294501433);
```

> You might also need to specify the DateTimeKind explicitly, depending on your exact requirements:

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
             .AddMilliseconds(1286294501433);
```