# How to convert to .net Datetime from Json Datetime format returned from ServiceStack implementation of Redis?

Tags: json, redis, servicestack

I am trying to retrieve from Redis where value is of Datetime type. Pasted Code snippet below. I am using ServiceStack.Redis to interact with Redis.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; // current value is dt is --> 8/2/2012 12:18:38 AM
redisClient.Set<DateTime>("myKey", DateTime.Now);
```

I am getting the value back from Redis using the following command.

```
var dtvalue = redisClient.Get("myKey");
```

the value which, dtValue variable hold is

```
\/Date(1343846917510+0530)\/
```

**How can I convert this into .net DateTime? I am using C#.**

I tried the following but not getting the correct result.

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(1343842541241);
```

I am getting the value is d as 1/2/0001 1:19:44 PM.

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IRedisClient.Get<T>()` e.g:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
redisClient.Set<DateTime>("myKey", DateTime.Now);
var dtFromRedis redisClient.Get<DateTime>("myKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Trivia: How to convert a JSON2.org DateTime string to C# DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094118/trivia-how-to-convert-a-json2-org-datetime-string-to-c-sharp-datetime)

For your exact example this is how you could convert it:

```
    var unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    var ticksSinceEpoch = 1343846917510 * 10000;
    var time = new DateTime(unixEpoch.Ticks + ticksSinceEpoch).AddHours(5).AddMinutes(30);
```